Import luxon and luxon adapter as static resources in LWC
I am trying to import luxon and luxon adapter as static resources in my LWC child component, but it throws an error when trying to load luxon and luxon adapter.
Here are the steps I followed. (When I only had chartjs it was working fine.)

Download chartjs from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.min.js and upload it as a static resource.
Download the minified version of luxon from https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/install?id=es6. I am not sure if I should use the "Basic browser setup" or "ES6" file (I tried both). Upload it as a static resource.
Download the chartjs adapter luxon from https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon. I took the file in this link: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon. Upload it as a static resource.
Update my lwc js code as follows:

import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'; //load script from chartjs
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ChartJs';
import adapter from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/LuxonAdapter';
import luxon from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/LuxonDateTime';

// Child component for rendering a chart
export default class GenericChart extends LightningElement {
    @api chartConfig;
    chart;
    isChartInitialized;

    renderedCallback() {
        this.loadScripts();
    }

    async loadScripts() {
        await loadScript(this, chartjs)
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading Chart.js:', error);
            });
        await loadScript(this, luxon)
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading Luxon Date Time:', error);
            });
        await loadScript(this, adapter)
            .then(() => {
                this.initializeChart();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading Luxon adapter:', error);
            });
        this.isChartInitialized = true;
    }

    initializeChart() {
        const ctx = this.template.querySelector('canvas.linechart').getContext('2d');
        this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.chartConfig)));
    }
}


Would it be possible to add the ChartJS version (or where exactly you've got ChartJS from) to your question? And the exact error you got, and if it happens during loading Luxon or during loading the adapter? Thanks.

Hi @FelixvanHove, thank you for reaching out. I added the link to the chartjs version above. However, the error message I got was generic, no details about the error, and it was for both Luxon and the adapter.

The luxon lib worked for me out of the box. Required version: "Basic browser setup".
The minified version of the luxon chartjs adapter crashed however. Unfortunately the developers only provide Javascript with import statements in their repo - not suitable for LWC, and neither the Javascript used for the minified version. Minified Javascript is cumbersome to debug.
Instead of spending time on this, I took the adapter from the repository, modified it slightly and incorporated it into the LWC:
[...]
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ChartJs';
import luxon from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/LuxonDateTime';
[...]

export default class GenericChart extends LightningElement {
[...]
    async loadScripts() {
        await loadScript(this, chartjs);
        await loadScript(this, luxon);
        await this.initializeAdapter();
        await this.initializeChart();
        this.isChartInitialized = true;
    }

    async initializeAdapter() {

        const DateTime = window.luxon.DateTime;

        const FORMATS = {
            datetime: DateTime.DATETIME_MED_WITH_SECONDS,
            millisecond: 'h:mm:ss.SSS a',
            second: DateTime.TIME_WITH_SECONDS,
            minute: DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE,
            hour: {hour: 'numeric'},
            day: {day: 'numeric', month: 'short'},
            week: 'DD',
            month: {month: 'short', year: 'numeric'},
            quarter: "'Q'q - yyyy",
            year: {year: 'numeric'}
        };

        window.Chart._adapters._date.override({
        
            _id: 'luxon', // DEBUG

            /**
             * @private
             */
            _create: function(time) {
                return DateTime.fromMillis(time, this.options);
            },

            init(chartOptions) {
                if (!this.options.locale) {
                this.options.locale = chartOptions.locale;
                }
            },

            formats: function() {
                return FORMATS;
            },

            parse: function(value, format) {
                const options = this.options;

                const type = typeof value;
                if (value === null || type === 'undefined') {
                return null;
                }

                if (type === 'number') {
                value = this._create(value);
                } else if (type === 'string') {
                if (typeof format === 'string') {
                    value = DateTime.fromFormat(value, format, options);
                } else {
                    value = DateTime.fromISO(value, options);
                }
                } else if (value instanceof Date) {
                value = DateTime.fromJSDate(value, options);
                } else if (type === 'object' && !(value instanceof DateTime)) {
                value = DateTime.fromObject(value, options);
                }

                return value.isValid ? value.valueOf() : null;
            },

            format: function(time, format) {
                const datetime = this._create(time);
                return typeof format === 'string'
                ? datetime.toFormat(format)
                : datetime.toLocaleString(format);
            },

            add: function(time, amount, unit) {
                const args = {};
                args[unit] = amount;
                return this._create(time).plus(args).valueOf();
            },

            diff: function(max, min, unit) {
                return this._create(max).diff(this._create(min)).as(unit).valueOf();
            },

            startOf: function(time, unit, weekday) {
                if (unit === 'isoWeek') {
                weekday = Math.trunc(Math.min(Math.max(0, weekday), 6));
                const dateTime = this._create(time);
                return dateTime.minus({days: (dateTime.weekday - weekday + 7) % 7}).startOf('day').valueOf();
                }
                return unit ? this._create(time).startOf(unit).valueOf() : time;
            },

            endOf: function(time, unit) {
                return this._create(time).endOf(unit).valueOf();
            }
        });
    }
[...]
}

This worked for me. Modifications of the original adapter are marginal. It also has the advantage that you can more easily modify the adapter, e.g. for time.*.

Hi Felix, thanks a lot! This is wonderful. It works perfectly, except for the part with this.isChartInitialized = true. It was loading indefinitely but when I moved it to the top of the loadScripts method, it worked (I am not sure why).

Sorry, I'm neither sure why the boolean variable behaved strangely. I'm glad that you could solve this too!
